# How to select another radio button through selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation

[image]

I already try everything but could run

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
    
        WebElement ab = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='userSelectTabsLinks' ][contains(.,'Company')]/input[@name='seller_type']"));
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        ab.click();
```

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). You may like to consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: please share a piece of HTML code to clarify

Comment: there's ID's there... just use those.  ex: //input[@id='buyer']